# How to access information from List type to display in view

Tags: c#, json

How do I go about taking the information from the List and populating the table with the selected country? I am able to access the name of each country to populate the dropdown list and add the 3digit alpha code as an ID but I am at a a loss on how to access the rest of the information that I got from the API. I know this is probably a really simple fix but I can't, for the life of me, figure it out. (EDIT: In the view I was thinking of using an onclick event to capture the ID of a selected country from the list to display the information but I am unsure how to implement this in c#)

I can make a call to the api through the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CountryViewer.Models;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CountryUI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        string Baseurl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";


        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<CountryModel> country = new List<CountryModel>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");

                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var CountryResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    country = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryModel>>(CountryResponse);


                }

                return View(country);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Then I am able to model that information into a list type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CountryViewer.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public CountryModel()
        {
            Currencies = new List<CurrencyModel>();
        }

        public CountryModel(string alpha3Code, string name, int population, string flag, string[] timeZones, string capital, List<CurrencyModel> currencies, string[] borders)
        {
            Alpha3Code = alpha3Code ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(alpha3Code));
            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            Population = population;
            Flag = flag ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(flag));
            TimeZones = timeZones ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(timeZones));
            Capital = capital ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(capital));
            Currencies = currencies ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currencies));
            Borders = borders ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(borders));
        }



        //Alpha3code
        public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }
        //country name
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //population
        public int Population { get; set; }
        //public string Languages { get; set; }
        //flag
        public string Flag { get; set; }
        //timezone
        public string[] TimeZones { get; set; }
        //capital
        public string Capital { get; set; }
        //currency
        public List<CurrencyModel> Currencies { get; set; }
        ////bordering countries
        public string[] Borders { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CurrencyModel
    {

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Symbol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I am able to access that information in the view and display a list of country names for the user to select.

```
@model IEnumerable<CountryViewer.Models.CountryModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<h1>Index</h1>

@*<p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>*@

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <option id="@item.Alpha3Code" onclick=CaptureID(@item.Alpha3Code)>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)


                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="">Submit</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-responsive" style="width:400px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alpha3Code)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Population)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Flag)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Capital)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>



                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        selected country 3 digit alpha code
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                         selected country name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                         selected country population
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                         selected country flag
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        selected country capital
                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the JSON is the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".af"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AF",
        "alpha3Code": "AFG",
        "callingCodes": [
            "93"
        ],
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AF",
            "Afġānistān"
        ],
        "region": "Asia",
        "subregion": "Southern Asia",
        "population": 27657145,
        "latlng": [
            33.0,
            65.0
        ],
        "demonym": "Afghan",
        "area": 652230.0,
        "gini": 27.8,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+04:30"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "IRN",
            "PAK",
            "TKM",
            "UZB",
            "TJK",
            "CHN"
        ],
        "nativeName": "افغانستان",
        "numericCode": "004",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "AFN",
                "name": "Afghan afghani",
                "symbol": "؋"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "ps",
                "iso639_2": "pus",
                "name": "Pashto",
                "nativeName": "پښتو"
            },
            {
                "iso639_1": "uz",
                "iso639_2": "uzb",
                "name": "Uzbek",
                "nativeName": "Oʻzbek"
            },
            {
                "iso639_1": "tk",
                "iso639_2": "tuk",
                "name": "Turkmen",
                "nativeName": "Türkmen"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Afghanistan",
            "es": "Afganistán",
            "fr": "Afghanistan",
            "ja": "アフガニスタン",
            "it": "Afghanistan",
            "br": "Afeganistão",
            "pt": "Afeganistão",
            "nl": "Afghanistan",
            "hr": "Afganistan",
            "fa": "افغانستان"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "SAARC",
                "name": "South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": []
            }
        ],
        "cioc": "AFG"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".ax"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AX",
        "alpha3Code": "ALA",
        "callingCodes": [
            "358"
        ],
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AX",
            "Aaland",
            "Aland",
            "Ahvenanmaa"
        ],
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Northern Europe",
        "population": 28875,
        "latlng": [
            60.116667,
            19.9
        ],
        "demonym": "Ålandish",
        "area": 1580.0,
        "gini": null,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+02:00"
        ],
        "borders": [],
        "nativeName": "Åland",
        "numericCode": "248",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "EUR",
                "name": "Euro",
                "symbol": "€"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "sv",
                "iso639_2": "swe",
                "name": "Swedish",
                "nativeName": "svenska"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Åland",
            "es": "Alandia",
            "fr": "Åland",
            "ja": "オーランド諸島",
            "it": "Isole Aland",
            "br": "Ilhas de Aland",
            "pt": "Ilhas de Aland",
            "nl": "Ålandeilanden",
            "hr": "Ålandski otoci",
            "fa": "جزایر الند"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "EU",
                "name": "European Union",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": []
            }
        ],
        "cioc": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Albania",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".al"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AL",
        "alpha3Code": "ALB",
        "callingCodes": [
            "355"
        ],
        "capital": "Tirana",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AL",
            "Shqipëri",
            "Shqipëria",
            "Shqipnia"
        ],
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Southern Europe",
        "population": 2886026,
        "latlng": [
            41.0,
            20.0
        ],
        "demonym": "Albanian",
        "area": 28748.0,
        "gini": 34.5,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "MNE",
            "GRC",
            "MKD",
            "KOS"
        ],
        "nativeName": "Shqipëria",
        "numericCode": "008",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "ALL",
                "name": "Albanian lek",
                "symbol": "L"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "sq",
                "iso639_2": "sqi",
                "name": "Albanian",
                "nativeName": "Shqip"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Albanien",
            "es": "Albania",
            "fr": "Albanie",
            "ja": "アルバニア",
            "it": "Albania",
            "br": "Albânia",
            "pt": "Albânia",
            "nl": "Albanië",
            "hr": "Albanija",
            "fa": "آلبانی"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "CEFTA",
                "name": "Central European Free Trade Agreement",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": []
            }
        ],
        "cioc": "ALB"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algeria",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".dz"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "DZ",
        "alpha3Code": "DZA",
        "callingCodes": [
            "213"
        ],
        "capital": "Algiers",
        "altSpellings": [
            "DZ",
            "Dzayer",
            "Algérie"
        ],
        "region": "Africa",
        "subregion": "Northern Africa",
        "population": 40400000,
        "latlng": [
            28.0,
            3.0
        ],
        "demonym": "Algerian",
        "area": 2381741.0,
        "gini": 35.3,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "TUN",
            "LBY",
            "NER",
            "ESH",
            "MRT",
            "MLI",
            "MAR"
        ],
        "nativeName": "الجزائر",
        "numericCode": "012",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "DZD",
                "name": "Algerian dinar",
                "symbol": "د.ج"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "ar",
                "iso639_2": "ara",
                "name": "Arabic",
                "nativeName": "العربية"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Algerien",
            "es": "Argelia",
            "fr": "Algérie",
            "ja": "アルジェリア",
            "it": "Algeria",
            "br": "Argélia",
            "pt": "Argélia",
            "nl": "Algerije",
            "hr": "Alžir",
            "fa": "الجزایر"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/dza.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "AU",
                "name": "African Union",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": [
                    "الاتحاد الأفريقي",
                    "Union africaine",
                    "União Africana",
                    "Unión Africana",
                    "Umoja wa Afrika"
                ]
            },
            {
                "acronym": "AL",
                "name": "Arab League",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": [
                    "جامعة الدول العربية",
                    "Jāmiʻat ad-Duwal al-ʻArabīyah",
                    "League of Arab States"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "cioc": "ALG"
    },
    {
        "name": "American Samoa",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".as"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AS",
        "alpha3Code": "ASM",
        "callingCodes": [
            "1684"
        ],
        "capital": "Pago Pago",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AS",
            "Amerika Sāmoa",
            "Amelika Sāmoa",
            "Sāmoa Amelika"
        ],
        "region": "Oceania",
        "subregion": "Polynesia",
        "population": 57100,
        "latlng": [
            -14.33333333,
            -170.0
        ],
        "demonym": "American Samoan",
        "area": 199.0,
        "gini": null,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC-11:00"
        ],
        "borders": [],
        "nativeName": "American Samoa",
        "numericCode": "016",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "USD",
                "name": "United State Dollar",
                "symbol": "$"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "en",
                "iso639_2": "eng",
                "name": "English",
                "nativeName": "English"
            },
            {
                "iso639_1": "sm",
                "iso639_2": "smo",
                "name": "Samoan",
                "nativeName": "gagana fa'a Samoa"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Amerikanisch-Samoa",
            "es": "Samoa Americana",
            "fr": "Samoa américaines",
            "ja": "アメリカ領サモア",
            "it": "Samoa Americane",
            "br": "Samoa Americana",
            "pt": "Samoa Americana",
            "nl": "Amerikaans Samoa",
            "hr": "Američka Samoa",
            "fa": "ساموآی آمریکا"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/asm.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [],
        "cioc": "ASA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".ad"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AD",
        "alpha3Code": "AND",
        "callingCodes": [
            "376"
        ],
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AD",
            "Principality of Andorra",
            "Principat d'Andorra"
        ],
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Southern Europe",
        "population": 78014,
        "latlng": [
            42.5,
            1.5
        ],
        "demonym": "Andorran",
        "area": 468.0,
        "gini": null,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "FRA",
            "ESP"
        ],
        "nativeName": "Andorra",
        "numericCode": "020",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "EUR",
                "name": "Euro",
                "symbol": "€"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "ca",
                "iso639_2": "cat",
                "name": "Catalan",
                "nativeName": "català"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Andorra",
            "es": "Andorra",
            "fr": "Andorre",
            "ja": "アンドラ",
            "it": "Andorra",
            "br": "Andorra",
            "pt": "Andorra",
            "nl": "Andorra",
            "hr": "Andora",
            "fa": "آندورا"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/and.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [],
        "cioc": "AND"
    },
    {
        "name": "Angola",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".ao"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AO",
        "alpha3Code": "AGO",
        "callingCodes": [
            "244"
        ],
        "capital": "Luanda",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AO",
            "República de Angola",
            "ʁɛpublika de an'ɡɔla"
        ],
        "region": "Africa",
        "subregion": "Middle Africa",
        "population": 25868000,
        "latlng": [
            -12.5,
            18.5
        ],
        "demonym": "Angolan",
        "area": 1246700.0,
        "gini": 58.6,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "COG",
            "COD",
            "ZMB",
            "NAM"
        ],
        "nativeName": "Angola",
        "numericCode": "024",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "AOA",
                "name": "Angolan kwanza",
                "symbol": "Kz"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "pt",
                "iso639_2": "por",
                "name": "Portuguese",
                "nativeName": "Português"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Angola",
            "es": "Angola",
            "fr": "Angola",
            "ja": "アンゴラ",
            "it": "Angola",
            "br": "Angola",
            "pt": "Angola",
            "nl": "Angola",
            "hr": "Angola",
            "fa": "آنگولا"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ago.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [
            {
                "acronym": "AU",
                "name": "African Union",
                "otherAcronyms": [],
                "otherNames": [
                    "الاتحاد الأفريقي",
                    "Union africaine",
                    "União Africana",
                    "Unión Africana",
                    "Umoja wa Afrika"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "cioc": "ANG"
    },
    {
        "name": "Anguilla",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".ai"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AI",
        "alpha3Code": "AIA",
        "callingCodes": [
            "1264"
        ],
        "capital": "The Valley",
        "altSpellings": [
            "AI"
        ],
        "region": "Americas",
        "subregion": "Caribbean",
        "population": 13452,
        "latlng": [
            18.25,
            -63.16666666
        ],
        "demonym": "Anguillian",
        "area": 91.0,
        "gini": null,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC-04:00"
        ],
        "borders": [],
        "nativeName": "Anguilla",
        "numericCode": "660",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "XCD",
                "name": "East Caribbean dollar",
                "symbol": "$"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "en",
                "iso639_2": "eng",
                "name": "English",
                "nativeName": "English"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Anguilla",
            "es": "Anguilla",
            "fr": "Anguilla",
            "ja": "アンギラ",
            "it": "Anguilla",
            "br": "Anguila",
            "pt": "Anguila",
            "nl": "Anguilla",
            "hr": "Angvila",
            "fa": "آنگویلا"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/aia.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [],
        "cioc": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Antarctica",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".aq"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "AQ",
        "alpha3Code": "ATA",
        "callingCodes": [
            "672"
        ],
        "capital": "",
        "altSpellings": [],
        "region": "Polar",
        "subregion": "",
        "population": 1000,
        "latlng": [
            -74.65,
            4.48
        ],
        "demonym": "",
        "area": 1.4E7,
        "gini": null,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC-03:00",
            "UTC+03:00",
            "UTC+05:00",
            "UTC+06:00",
            "UTC+07:00",
            "UTC+08:00",
            "UTC+10:00",
            "UTC+12:00"
        ],
        "borders": [],
        "nativeName": "Antarctica",
        "numericCode": "010",
        "currencies": [
            {
                "code": "AUD",
                "name": "Australian dollar",
                "symbol": "$"
            },
            {
                "code": "GBP",
                "name": "British pound",
                "symbol": "£"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "iso639_1": "en",
                "iso639_2": "eng",
                "name": "English",
                "nativeName": "English"
            },
            {
                "iso639_1": "ru",
                "iso639_2": "rus",
                "name": "Russian",
                "nativeName": "Русский"
            }
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Antarktika",
            "es": "Antártida",
            "fr": "Antarctique",
            "ja": "南極大陸",
            "it": "Antartide",
            "br": "Antártida",
            "pt": "Antárctida",
            "nl": "Antarctica",
            "hr": "Antarktika",
            "fa": "جنوبگان"
        },
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ata.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [],
        "cioc": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".ag"
        ],...]
```

There is more JSON but you get the hint.

Comment: if i understand correctly, you need to loop in the View

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that the user can select the country from the populated list and, after the selection is made, the information of the country selected is displayed. each country in the list has an individual ID. How do I go about looping through so that the correct country's information is shown on the UI? I understand the I can use a foreach but I am unsure how to filter using the ID, or if that is even the right move in this case.